# Alt+drag in Sketch, keep same layer name

Tags: sketch-app

When I copy  an element with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, it keeps the same name in the layer panel.

When I copy an element by holding down the alt key and dragging it somewhere, 'copy' gets added to the layername which clutters the layer panel.

Is it posible to give alt+drag the same naming behaviour as <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

It is possible.

Please go to `Sketch > Preferences(CMD+,) > Layers, uncheck "Rename duplicated layers."`

Sketch will no longer rename the duplicated layers when you alt+drag them.